# Echo inside parameter of base_url()

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this code below:

```
href="<?= base_url('classes/number_of_class')?>"
```

I'm thinking of something like this

```
href="<?= base_url('classes/$class['number']')?>"
```

I don't have any idea how to multi quote this or if it is even possible. Any other way how to do this is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<?= base_url("classes/{$class['number']}")?>
```

Or this

```
<?= base_url("classes/" . $class['number'])?>
```

Comment: Ohhh. Thanks. Still needs 8 minutes to choose this as answer though.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
href="<?= base_url('classes/'.$class['number'])?>"
```